# React js - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): t._innerWindow(...).widgetReady is not a function

Tags: reactjs, trading, tradingview-api

```
 this._innerWindowLoaded.then(function () {
      t._innerWindow().widgetReady(function () {
        t._ready = !0;
        for (var e = 0, o = t._readyHandlers; e < o.length; e++) {
          var n = o[e];
          try {
            n.call(t);
          } catch (t) {
            console.error(t);
          }
        }
        t._innerWindow().initializationFinished();
      });
    });
  }),
```

The code is of charting_library.min.js which you can find easily in the github. I am running through this error. Actually I am connecting trading API from finnhub.io .

So needed some help in this issue as soon as possible

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error in Production then instead of running the command `serve -s build` just run `server build` without `-s` parameter.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Comments are used for clarifying the questions. And not answers. Please try to elaborate why removing the `-s` will help.

Comment: That is what the tradingview guys said and they have explained in this link https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/issues/15#issuecomment-411001758

Comment: Please consider adding the link to your answer, and maybe even quote something from it.

Comment: Ok i will try to make it better